# Minecraft doesn't run through eclipse

Tags: minecraft

I am writing a mod for minecraft, I still can not configure the environment, help meф

[image]

```
Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.MissingRequiredOptionException: Missing required option(s) ['accessToken', 'version']
at joptsimple.OptionParser.ensureRequiredOptions(OptionParser.java:447)
at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:437)
at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:47)
```

Comment: Did you use `./gradlew setupDecompWorkspace eclipse` to set up Eclipse, or did you try to do it by hand for some reason?

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica used but folder minecraft was without directories, on this opened not MCLauncher13/eclipse and simply MCLauncher13

Comment: That's the wrong way to do it and is why you're having the problem. Use the script the way everyone else does and open the project that it makes.

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica add the instructions simply I am from Russia and the translator does not cope well with its task I almost do not understand you

Comment: Consider re-asking this in your native language on [Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/) (and deleting this one).

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica I recorded a video for you https://youtu.be/6E6HnbqF5OM

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica Sorry for the quality I will explain first with the cd command open the deriktoriya with forge then enter gradlew.bat setupDecompWorkspace eclipse writes build failure

Comment: The quality is fine. Your issue is a common one. My latest link tells you how to fix it.

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica after clicking on your link I'm afraid I didn't find anything related to my problem

Comment: Isn't that the same error that you got in your video?

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica I don't really understand

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica I changed the http Protocol to https for Maven and the rest the same error

Comment: @Joseph Sible-Reinstate Monica as I understood build.gradle loads something from here https://files.minecraftforge.net/maven/ the connection is secure but the error is the same